# Change Chrome Extension Icon dynamically with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, icons

I am making a schedule chrome extension that will display time left in a certain period. I want to do it so when there is 37:03 left(stored in  the variable `timeLeft`, it will display it in the icon. For example, AdBlocker dynamically changes their logo to display the amount of ads being blocked. (see photo)[image: Ad Blocker blocking 2 ads on a page]

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [browser Action](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction), what you said is called `Badge`, you can use `browserAction.setBadgeText` to dynamically change the logo.

> Browser actions can optionally display a badge — a bit of text that is layered over the icon. **Badges make it easy to update the browser action to display a small amount of information about the state of the extension.**
>
> Because the badge has limited space, it should have 4 characters or less.
>
> Set the text and color of the badge using `browserAction.setBadgeText` and `browserAction.setBadgeBackgroundColor`, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Note that Haibara Ai's answer explains what happens in the case of ABP, and is the easiest method, in general you can make a dynamic icon by painting what you want into a `<canvas>` and updating the icon with resulting `imageData`.

You can see an example of this in [Google Mail Checker sample extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#google-mail-checker), see `drawIconAtRotation()` function.

This may be useful if the information you want to convey isn't textual or doesn't fit on a badge (and "XX:XX" is already straining it).